# Login into Vagrant without keys, and without vagrant user default password

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I on purpose messed up with auth keys, and also deleted the password for user `vagrant` which was also `vagrant`
Now when I `vagrant up` it stops here

```
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

And can't login in any way. Can I use somehow provision to reset my password, or push another auth key?

```
VirtualBox: 5.0.24
Vagrant: 1.8.1
```

Someone adviced to boot a live system and chroot into broken system and change password. Trying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open VirtualBox application.
Show wanted machine window.
There you have login prompt.
Enter `root` as login and `vagrant` as password.
Logged in. Change whatever you want.
Using `ssh -p 2222 root@127.0.0.1` and using `vagrant` password does not work.